# How to retrieve TextBox value in ViewState from its ID

Tags: asp.net

I am building many textboxes programmatically in my ASP.NET page, after I've clicked a button, I would like to process those values, is there any possibility to retrieve them from their ID in ViewState ?

Here is my code :

Reference of the table in the aspx :

```
<asp:Table ID="Distances" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Inherit"></asp:Table>
```

Then in code behind after creating all the rows and cells, I add a textbox into some of them :

```
Distances.Rows[j].Cells[i].Controls.Add(CreateTB(distance.ToString(), (i + j * rows).ToString(), false));

    protected TextBox CreateTB(string text, string id, bool ebanled = true)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox() { Text = text, ID = id, Enabled = ebanled};
        tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(OnTBChanged);
        return tb;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewState` is enabled by default, so it should already work that the `Text` property is persisted across postbacks.

So you could for example use `FindControl("TextBoxID")` or enumerate them to get the refernce to  the `TextBox` (assuming that they are added to a container-control like `Panel`):

```
foreach(TextBox txt in MyPanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    String text = txt.Text;
}
```

or

```
TextBox txt = (TextBox)MyPanel.FindControl("TextBox1")
String text = txt.Text;
```

I assume you're not recreating those `TextBoxes` on postbacks. Therefore you need to use the same ID as before and recreate them in `Page_Load` at the latest stage in page's life-cycle. So you can create them in an event, but you cannot recreate them there.

You should show your code where you create them dynamically, then i could be more specific.

[TRULY UNDERSTANDING DYNAMIC CONTROLS](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx)

Comment: I've just done it : my problem is that my table rows are lost during the operation, therefore I don't know where my textboxes are ;)